# search package by name in eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have tried the code below but there is no match. Please help me with this.

```
    SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern(packageName,IJavaSearchConstants.PACKAGE,IJavaSearchConstants.PACKAGE,IJavaSearchConstants.ALL_OCCURRENCES);
    IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();
    PackageSearchRequestor requestor=new PackageSearchRequestor();
    SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
    searchEngine.search(pattern, new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine.getDefaultSearchParticipant() }, scope, requestor, null);
```

Note:I currently achieve this by iterating through all projects in workspace and calling getAllPackageFragmentRoots() of IJavaProject and iterating the package and matching the element name. But i think using SearchPattern will be better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You parameters the `SearchPattern.createPattern` do not match the valid values described in the JavaDoc. You probably want something like:

```
SearchPattern.createPattern(packageName, IJavaSearchConstants.PACKAGE,
            IJavaSearchConstants.ALL_OCCURRENCES, SearchPattern.R_EXACT_MATCH);
```